# SQL Select rows with same key and different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let me demonstrate, let's say we have this table:

| key | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | type_a |
| 1 | type_b |
| 2 | type_c |
| 1 | type_c |
| 3 | type_a |
| 4 | type_c |

So now I want to retrieve the single key (distinct) whose type can be a and b.

So the answer would be

| key |
| --- |
| 1 |

So if it only had type_a or type_b it would be ignored, it needs to have both type_a and type_b for that specific key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select key
from t
where type in ('type_a', 'type_b')
group by key
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note:  This assumes that your table does not have duplicates.  If you have duplicates, use:

```
having count(distinct type) = 2;
```

Comment: Oh okay I thought that the IN would work sort of like an OR where it would return on both cases separately. Going to try it.

Comment: @BryceSoker . . . That is how `IN` works.  The key here is aggregation and `HAVING`.

Comment: And if `type` is joined then you do `having count(*) = (select count(*) from jointable)`

Comment: Sorry, might be doing something wrong but I'm still getting keys with either one or the other, not only the ones with both.

Comment: @BryceSoker . . . That suggests that you either have duplicates in the data (which are fixed by using `count(distinct)`) or you have left out the `having` clause.

Comment: Yep had some duplicates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
select key  
from t  
where type in ('type_a', 'type_b')  
group by key  
having count(1) = 2
```

For any other occurrence: simply replace in the `IN (...)` part, and make sure `count(1) = the number of elements inside IN ()`.
For example:

```
select key  
from t  
where type in ('type_a', 'type_b', 'type_c', 'type_d')  
group by key  
having count(1) = 4
```

Comment: Sorry, might be doing something wrong but I'm still getting keys with either one or the other, not only the ones with both.

Comment: Might probably have duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select key
from `project.dataset.table`
group by key
having count(distinct if(type in ('type_a', 'type_b'), type, null)) = 2
```